# How to roll back Wordpress version or prevent migration from forcing update?

Tags: plugins, themes

So, we have a custom theme built with the SiteOrigin Page Builder. Until recently this has played somewhat nicely with Wordpress 5. A recent update to Advanced Custom Fields has more or less completely broken our ability to edit the site's front page. So, I would like to take us back to WP 4 keep us there for as long as practically possible.

Our production site is still on the old code base, but every time I have moved the site I have been forced to upgrade, which then introduces all of the breaking changes again.

The functionality we need is broken with or without the Classic editor, so shy of going on an extensive bug hunt which is above my level, rolling back (if possible) is the only option I really have.

Comment: Would it not make more sense to go back to the previous version of ACF that you know worked, and stay on it until the ACF devs have fixed your support request? Keep in mind that if it's broken with the classic editor plugin there's no reason to think that moving to 4.9.x would fix the issue, it sounds like the real problem is a lack of testing before updating plugins, and a botched ACF update release, or poke SiteOrigin Page Builder support?

Comment: Additionally, there's nothing in WordPress itself forcing you to upgrade, where are these forced upgrades coming from?

Comment: The last time the codebase worked the way it was supposed to was with version, 4.9. I don't know what is forcing the updates but anytime I move the production database to an old version of the codebase I get forced to do a database update and voila, I get Gutenberged.

Comment: When you say forced to do a database update, do you mean the ACF database update? ACF will show a message that says your Database needs to be updated, but what it really means is the ACF entries in your database. If so, then what you really need to do is roll back the ACF version, not the WP version.

Comment: No, I mean Wordpress core. If I move the site from the production environment to a staging environment (copy the code and files, copy the database and run the wp-cli search-replace script) I am informed that I have to update the database which forces me to update to wordpress 5.

Comment: If you don't want to use Gutenberg, install the [Classic Editor plugin](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/).

Comment: Whatever is broken is killing the content tab in both editors.

Comment: Rolling back ACF Pro fixed the issue temporarily, thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: Make sure to submit a bug report to the ACF developers. They should either be able to help you solve it or release a fix for everyone if it's affecting other users.